# Como adicionar espaço em "boxplot" e centralizar a mediana

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de fazer duas modificações no seguinte gráfico

[image: gráfico 1]:

1. Deixar um pequeno espaço entre os boxplot verde(F) e laranja(s)
2. Colocar o ponto referente a mediana no centro de cada boxplot (os pontos estão aparecendo na extremidade do boxplot e quando os dois plots tem o mesmo valor de mediana, só um ponto é plotado).

Alguém sabe quais alterações devo fazer em meu script?

Minha planilha pode ser acessada pelo link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X-gmhUmUqcIJmFtpHwaBO6fclJIUK4Sc

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda, abaixo deixo a amostragem:

```
library(ggplot2)

head(dados)
dados$warfare <- factor(dados$warfare, levels=c("war1", "war2", "Post"))

ggplot(dados, aes(x=warfare, y=Abund, group=warfare:habitat_F_S, colour = as.factor(habitat_F_S), fill=habitat_F_S)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Dark2") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", lwd=1, aes(group=habitat_F_S, colour=habitat_F_S)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, colour="black", geom="point", shape=18, size=1,show_guide = FALSE, aes(group=habitat_F_S, colour=habitat_F_S)) +
  facet_wrap(~ specie, nrow=5) + 
  labs(x="time", y="Abund", colour="Habitat", fill="Habitat") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para alterar a posição de plotagem dos grupos utilize a função `position=position_dodge(1)`

**Exemplo:**

```
p<-ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1))
p
```

Fonte: [STHDA - GGPLOT Guide](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-box-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization)

Comment: Olá Alexandre, obrigada pelo comentário. Mas não consegui fazer o que eu queria com o seu comando. Não sei se meu texto ficou claro, mas eu queria simplesmente add um pequeno espaço entre cada plot laranja e verde que estão unidos.

Comment: Fran, entendi, alterei a resposta para atender a necessidade que citou.

Comment: agora funcionou, obrigada! eu avaliei como positiva sua resposta, mas alguém havia avaliado como negativa antes..

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que o código abaixo pode te ajudar.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=warfare, y=Abund, group=warfare:habitat_F_S, colour = as.factor(habitat_F_S), fill=habitat_F_S)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Dark2") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", lwd=1, aes(group=habitat_F_S, colour=habitat_F_S)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", size=2, shape=18, colour="black", show.legend=FALSE, aes(group=habitat_F_S), position=position_dodge(1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ specie, nrow=5) + 
  labs(x="time", y="Abund", colour="Habitat", fill="Habitat") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas alterações em relação ao código original foram:

- `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position=position_dodge(1))`: o argumento `position=position_dodge(1)` desloca os boxplots verde e laranja
- `stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", size=2, shape=18, colour="black", show.legend=FALSE, aes(group=habitat_F_S), position=position_dodge(1)): o argumento`position=position_dodge(1)` desloca os pontos para o meio dos boxplots. Pintei os pontos de preto para destacá-los, pois não faria sentido que eles tivessem a cor dos próprios boxplots.

Particularmente, apesar de manter `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)`, não concordo com ela. Tirar os outliers dos teus gráficos acaba distorcendo eles, fazendo com que o leitor não tenha como perceber que os teus dados realmente são. Estes dados possuem muitos outliers e retirar isto do gráfico é mentir a respeito do que tu está analisando.